# Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor Cannot Start Without a Machine Name

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2019, hololens

I am trying to deploy to Hololens 2 via USB. The build is successful but the deploy isn't.

The error message I am getting is

> Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor cannot start without
> a Machine Name. Open project properties and specify a Machine Name
> under 'Configuration Properties -> Debugging'

I am doing the follow:

- Selecting "Debug", "ARM64", and "Remote Machine"
- Debug -> Start without debugging.

That is when that error message appears.

I then went to Project > Properties > Configuration Properties > Debugging.

The options that I chose were as follows:

- Configuration: Active(Debug)
- Platform: ARM64
- Debugger to Launch: Remote Windows Debugger

I don't see where I can put in a machine name. The Remote Server Name = $(COMPUTERNAME), so I'm assuming this is what I need to change. If so, how do I change what this value is represented by? Where would I go to find out the name of my Hololens2 machine? I assume, This PC -> Devices and Drives.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to select "Device" and not "Remote Machine" if you are going through USB.

See  [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/using-visual-studio)  for specifics.

Comment: What about when I connect via wifi? I followed the instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/using-visual-studio#enabling-developer-mode for deploying via wifi using ipv4, but it still says I need a machine name. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Ah, I figured out what I was doing wrong when connecting to wifi. I had it set to ARM64 and on the Configuration settings, I was using ARM. Bingo.

Comment: Having the same problem. I'm following their instructions, but I don't get prompted to input a PIN. It defaults to debugging via WiFi when I have "Device" selected.